# Where should the text in parentheses be placed?

Tags: grammar

In the sentence:

> The constant IO::SEEK_CUR assumes that
>   the offset is relative to the current
>   position (which may be negative).

`offset` is meant to be negative, not `current_position`. Is the above sentence correct or is one of the following the correct one:

> The constant IO::SEEK_CUR assumes that
>   the offset (which may be negative) is
>   relative to the current position.

or

> The constant IO::SEEK_CUR assumes that
>   the offset, which may be negative, is
>   relative to the current position.

Answer (score 1):

Generally text in parentheses should be immediately following the text it is modifying.  Therefore,

> The constant IO::SEEK_CUR assumes that
>   the offset (which may be negative) is
>   relative to the current position.

would be more appropriate than the first option.  The third option,

> The constant IO::SEEK_CUR assumes that
>   the offset, which may be negative, is
>   relative to the current position.

would be ok as well, but the second most clearly communicates the meaning you're trying to convey.